# Implement unnecessary Interface members or Create a new Interface?

Tags: c#, interface

General architecture problem i have been thinking about

If I have an interface, and 5 classes that implement that interface, but one class does not need to implement one of the interface members, should I:

1. Create a seperate interface for that one class
2. Implement the
   original interface but leave the methods empty
3. Implement the original interface but mark the unneccessary methods in some way
   (e.g obsolete attribute)

An example is if I have an interface IRepository and 5 seperate repositories for 5 entities, but for one entity I dont want to be able to update records.

I have currently sided toward option 3, but obsolete does not seem a correct description.

any ideas?

by the way I know this is quite broad and objective but I would like to hear some opinions about the best way to go.

Comment: Either, create a new interface, that all the other interfaces inherit or, implement the extra member but throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: If you decide to throw a NotSupportedException, make sure that you have some property that tells you this before calling it, like IList does with [`IList<T>.IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.isreadonly.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create another interface and inherite the ones you actually use

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository
{
    void Read();
}

public interface IRepository : IReadOnlyRepository
{
    void Write();
}
```

Then you could use the 'base' interface `IReadOnlyRepository` for the class you don't want the full implementation for.

Or, using you number 3. when the user attempts to invoke C from a class that does not implement it. Throw a `NotImplementedException`/`InvalidOperationException` or other relevant exception.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `Ib` should not repeat the members from `Ia`. They both should use correct syntax (`void A();`)

Comment: This seems like a really good idea, I never thought of inheriting interfaces, I inherit object all the time, but my mind never clocked that you could also inherit interfaces.

Comment: @Jodrell actually I was the first to answer - I previously had basic interface names but changed them with a planned later edit. "Get in there fast, edit later".

Answer (score 3):

Why not have 2 interfaces?

```
IReadableRepo
{
    Data Read();
}

IUpdatableRepo : IReadableRepo
{
    void Update();
}
```

Then implement the most relevant one in your classes.

Answer (score 3):

The formal answer would be to split it into `IRepository: IReadonlyRepository` and implement only the interfaces that are applicable.

But as a practical approach, for just one case, you could throw a NotSupported exception from the Update() method. That's your option 3 but you cannot really mark it efficiently for compile-time feedback.

Comment: `NotImplementedException` or `NotSupportedException`, the latter seems oxymoronic? +1 since your answer is the same as my comment.

Comment: I don't know which one is more oxymoron but NotSupported does sound better, less temporary-out-of-order. I will edit it in.

Comment: `NotImplementedException` usually points out a fault in the implementation (that for example you have forgotten to implement it, e.g. when not overriding a method defined in an abstract class), while `NotSupportedException` clearly says that this is completely intended.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in these matters, but from my point of view, I see an issue if you decide to stick with only one interface, it will seem you are offering a functionality that isn't supported.

In this case, you could have a base interface `ReadableRepository` extended by `UpdateableRepository`.

However, if for some reason you'll need a bit more properties for your repository, you might consider making separate interfaces for each (`IDoable1`, `IDoable2`, ..., `IDoableN`) and have your concrete classes implement what they need.